# Navigating in react-navigation with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I've read a bunch of the examples for react native navigation approaches with redux but most of them still seem to rely on doing the navigation in the component like:

`this.props.loginUser().then(this.props.navigation.push('Home"));`

where `this.props.LoginUser()` will dispatch `LOGGING_IN` and `LOGGED_IN` actions.

It seems like it would be cleaner to have the navigation handled as a pure function of the app state (outside of the component). i.e. when my auth reducer updates it state to be `loggedIn: true`, some navigation 'reducer' would then figure out that the app should be on the home screen and just go there. Same would be true for a `LOG_OUT` action.

Is there any best practice for achieving something like this? In react-navigation it feels like i'm fighting the framework to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can go with if you want to move away from using a navigator at all is to have a reducer keep track of which page you are on and then do conditional rendering of a page depending on the navigation state in the reducer. However, if you do this you will not have access to the niceties of the navigation bar and having the navigator keep track of your page stack for you. So if you want to use pages that allow you to navigate forwards and back in a logical flow as common use cases, I would recommend you stick with the current paradigm.